# Image of polynomial in $F[x]$ under derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $D$ be the formal polynomial differentiation map so that
$$D(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....+a_nx^n)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+....+na_nx^{n-1}$$
Find the image of $F[x]$ under $D$.

The answer is that the image of $F[x]$ under $D$ is $F[x]$, Im$(D)$

I understand as far as Im$(D)<F[x]$ (i.e., Im$(D)$ is a subring of $F[x]$) but I don't see why

Im$(D)=F[x]$. Can you guys please help?

Comment: What is your question? Of course, every given polynomial is a derivation of some polynomial. Try with the monomials first.

Comment: Let $p = p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + \dots + p_k x^k$. Assume that $D(a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_n x^n) = p$, substitute the definition of $D$, and compare corresponding powers of $x$.

Comment: I think the main thing to observe and use is that $F$ contains (an isomorphic copy of) the rational numbers as its prime subfield, so you can divide by non-zero integers in $F$.

Comment: Also, should $F$ have a positive characteristic, then $Im(D)$ will fail to be a subring. Therefore that claim may be less clear than you think in characteristic zero as well.

Comment: Can you also formally integrate a polynomial in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
D\Bigl(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigr)=
$$

Further hint: as soon as you have proved that $x^n\in\operatorname{Im}(D)$, *for every* $n\ge0$, you can apply the fact that $D$ is linear.

Comment: ...equals x^n. And D(1)=0. But why would that imply that Im(D)=F[x]?

Comment: @MathQ The map $D$ is linear and the polynomials $x^n$ (for $n\ge0$) span $F[x]$ as an $F$-vector space.

Comment: (1,x,x^2,...,x^n) spans F[x] but (1,x,x^2,...,x^(n-1) span Im(D). For me Im(D) is a subring of lower dimension and not equal to F[x]. i still dont get it :(

Comment: @MathQ There's no limitation on the degree in either case.